# "You won't have long to wait" and "You won't take long to wait"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between these sentences?

> You won't **have** long to wait.

> You won't **take** long to wait.

Answer (score 1):

Of the two, only the first is natural:

> You won't have long to wait

It means that the anticipated event will happen soon. The precise meaning of "long" depends on the context. If you are waiting for a doctor's appointment, it might mean a few minutes. If you are waiting for a package, it might mean a few days.

> You won't take long to wait

This is technically meaningless. Events "take" a period of time to begin or occur. The person who is waiting cannot "take" anything (with respect to time). A person must be participating in something for "take" to be meaningful. E.g.:

> You will take 50 minutes to complete the task.

But that's a little awkward—I can imagine someone saying it but not writing it. In speech and in writing, it would be more natural to phrase the idea with a dummy subject:

> It will take [you] 50 minutes to complete the task.

This would also sound more natural:

> The task will take 50 minutes to complete.

Comment: I would simply say _You won't wait long._